# Autosize grid columns as per value in grid value in extjs6

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I want to autosize the grid columns to max size of the content. How do i do this. i see only autoSize function on grid column, not sure how to use it.Say column header width is more then the column data width, that should be used.

I have used autosize function, It works, but i have few issues, I have to define the align property i.e text fields will be left and number fields will be on right, then heading text gets cut. I have locked columns in all reports, locked section gives some empty spaces.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1cr6

1. See column selling code. Its not showing full because of align: Right property. If you remove it will work.
   2.After DOW column empty space is coming.
2. Without minWidth Property columns wont scale properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this piece of documentation: [Ext.grid.column.Column - Setting sizes](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#ext-grid-column-column_setting-sizes). I don't think you can make columns scale to content. You can, however, set fixed sizes or make them [`flex`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-flex).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah i have given them fixed sizes.